# Log http request body , if exception has occured

Tags: java, spring-boot, request

I have been developing rest api service using spring boot.
This is my rest controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "owner/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody Owner owner) throws TimeoutException, SocketTimeoutException, SocketException {
        controller.login(owner);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("\"error\": 0");
    }
```

This is controller

```
 public JsonObject login(Owner loginOwner){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("email", loginOwner.getEmail());
        params.put("password", loginOwner.getPassword());
        if(GMoikaStringUtils.isEmpty(loginOwner.getEmail()) || !GMoikaStringUtils.isValidEmail(loginOwner.getEmail())){
            throw new InvalidUserInputException("Wrong email format", CLASS_NAME, "login", params, "owners/owner/login POST");
        }
        else{
            someLogic...
        }
    }
```

The question is, using this structure i should to create map with params inside each method.How to avoid creation of map inside each method and put all params into this map? I need "MAP" to show params in logs in case if exception is occured.
Maybe spring boot can do it , but i can't find my case in official docs. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to do this after an `InvalidUserInputException` is thrown, you could write an exception handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidUserInputException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ValidationError getError(InvalidUserInputException ex) {
    // ...
}
```

Since `InvalidUserInputException` is a custom exception, you could add a field of type `Object` in which you can pass your request body, for example:

```
throw new InvalidUserInputException("Wrong email format", loginOwner);
```

Now you can use the `toString()` method of the `Owner` object to log it. If you want to get it in a JSON style, you can use [Apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and their [`ToStringBuilder`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE)
        .append("email", email)
        .append("password", password)
        .toString();
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to rely on using the `toString()` method and just want to return the plain request body, you can also add `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter to an exception handler.

Before you do that, you have to wrap it though, because the request body can only be read once, and to overcome that problem you should "cache" the request body once it's read. To do this, you can use Spring their [`ContentCachingRequestWrapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingRequestWrapper.html).

To wrap it, you should write your own `Filter`. You can do this by extending from Spring their [`OncePerRequestFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) like this:

```
ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapper = (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request;
wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();

@Component
public class RequestWrapperFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        filterChain.doFilter(new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest), httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

Now you can get the request body in the exception handler by calling the `getContentAsByteArray()` method. To get the request body as a String you can use `IOUtils` from Apache Commons:

```
ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapper = (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request;
logger.warn("Input validation failed, request body: {}", IOUtils.toString(wrapper.getContentAsByteArray(), wrapper.getCharacterEncoding()));
```

This will log the entire request body as a string. Be careful with logging sensitive information though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any Logger, like **Log4j** and log in **else** statement:

**Steps to follow:**
1. Download latest log4j distribution.
2. Add log4j’s jar library into your program’s classpath.
3. Create log4j’s configuration.
4. Initialize log4j with the configuration.
5. Create a logger.
6. Put logging statements into your code.

```
 Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

public JsonObject login(Owner loginOwner){
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
    params.put("email", loginOwner.getEmail());
    params.put("password", loginOwner.getPassword());
    if(GMoikaStringUtils.isEmpty(loginOwner.getEmail()) || !GMoikaStringUtils.isValidEmail(loginOwner.getEmail())){
        throw new InvalidUserInputException("Wrong email format", CLASS_NAME, "login", params, "owners/owner/login POST");
    }
    else{
        logger.info("Log this event");
    }
}
```

Refer here: http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-configure-log4j-as-logging-mechanism-in-java

Comment: Thank for response, but it's not what i'm looking for. In my case when i throw InvalidUserInputException(it's my custom exception) i log params inside MAP to show to front end which params is not valid. I'm looking for structure that will replace my map with all params into more comfortable form

Comment: @ Алмас Абдразак  What are you reffering here "i log params inside MAP"

Comment: @АлмасАбдразак have you tried : "@ControllerAdvice" it listens to all exception occurs in controller and you can define a method in it for a specific controller

Comment: Yes i know, but how can i avoid using MAP to save all params? =)

Comment: @АлмасАбдразак just to be  clear when you say MAP it means hashMap right??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151714/discussion-between---and-mohit-sharma).